# Deserialise using java generics

Tags: java, class, generics, java-8

Consider this External execution class

```
public class ExternalCommands {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExternalCommands.class);

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public <T> CustomResponse<T> executeQuery(Clients client, Query query, Class<T> classType) throws Exception {
        if (Objects.isNull(clients))
            throw new Exception("external client is null in external commands");

        log.debug("Query : {}", query);
        Response queryResponse = clients.getElasticClient().executeQuery(query);
        log.debug("query response : {}", queryResponse);
        if (queryResponse.status() == 200) {
            JavaType javaType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(CustomResponse.class, classType);  // This is the coding sin m talking about
            return objectMapper.readValue(queryResponse.body().asInputStream(), javaType);
        }
    }
}
```

So Basically this `executeQuery` function fetches all the data as per `query` from an elastic client and deserialise it as per the generic `classType` as sent in function 
 BUT 
 this is more like *explicitly* doing the `deserialisation` instead of using *Generics*.

See below code on how this execution works along with inline comments :

```
public ArrayList<EmpData> getEmpData() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<EmpData> merchantUrnMap = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add("Added filter 1 here");
    filters.add("Added filter 2 here");
    filters.add("Added filter 3 here");

    ExternalCommands commands = new ExternalCommands();
    Query query = commands.getQuery(filters);
    // get "clients"

    // this is how it works now
    CustomResponse<EmpData> response = commands.executeQuery(clients, query, EmpData.class);

    // this is how i WANT IT TO WORK - without passing "EmpData.class"
    // but in this case <T> in "CustomResponse<T>" would not deserialise to "EmpData"
    // resulting in LinkedHashMap in deseralised object instead of class object
    // CustomResponse<EmpData> response = commands.<EmpData>executeQuery(clients, query); 


    // some operations
    return response

}
```

any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1: assuming that `constructParametricType` requires the `classType` argument to function properly, and you can't change the implementation of methods/classes that are implied but not provided in your posted code.

Your proposed method signature/invocation not possible due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in Java.

You use `classType` in the `constructParametricType(CustomResponse.class, classType)` call, and you're trying to replace `classType` with `T` somehow. This is impossible, because when the code is compiled, the `T` is erased completely. There is no way to do something like `constructParametricType(CustomResponse.class, T.class)` because `T` doesn't exist at runtime.

The correct solution is to pass in the class as a method argument, which is precisely what your existing approach does.

---

Case 2: you *really* want to have the call `commands.<EmpData>executeQuery(clients, query);` and you're willing to change anything to achieve that goal.

Since we cannot pass `T` as an argument to `constructParametricType`, it must be called as `constructParametricType(CustomResponse.class)`, yet it needs to return a `JavaType` representing `CustomResponse<T>`. The only way to do that is to declare

```
<T> JavaType<T> constructParametricType(Class<?> cls)
```

Note that `JavaType` now also has to be parameterized for the same reason (we can't get `T` at runtime). Finally, we have to declare

```
CustomResponse<T> readValue(InputStream stream, JavaType<T> javaType)
```

to match the declared return type of `executeQuery`.

After all of these changes, the line

```
CustomResponse<EmpData> response = commands.<EmpData>executeQuery(clients, query);
```

should compile. Here's a minimal example:

```
class CustomResponse<T> {}
class Clients{}
class Query{}
class EmpData{}

class ObjectMapper {
    JavaTypeFactory getTypeFactory() {
        return new JavaTypeFactory();
    }
    <T> CustomResponse<T> readValue(InputStream s, JavaType<T> j) {
        return new CustomResponse<>();
    }
}

class JavaTypeFactory {
    <T> JavaType<T> constructParametricType(Class<?> cls) {
        return new JavaType<>(cls);
    }
}

class JavaType<T> {
    JavaType(Class<?> cls) {}
}

class ExternalCommands {
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public <T> CustomResponse<T> executeQuery(Clients clients, Query query) throws Exception {
        InputStream queryResponseStream = null;
        JavaType<T> javaType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().<T>constructParametricType(CustomResponse.class);
        return objectMapper.readValue(queryResponseStream, javaType);
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    public void getEmpData() throws Exception {
        ExternalCommands commands = new ExternalCommands();
        Query query = null;
        Clients clients = null;
        CustomResponse<EmpData> response = commands.<EmpData>executeQuery(clients, query);
    }
}
```

Beware that some of the described changes might not be easy/possible given the rest of your system (especially parameterizing `JavaType`), and I don't recommend this approach. I recommend sticking with what you have; it's the cleanest approach IMO.